# SelectAll en el evento GotFocus con el ratón

Tags: c#, wpf

En WPF, tengo el siguiente código:

```
private void txtImporte_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    txtImporte.SelectAll();
}
```

Esto funciona perfectamente siempre y cuando llegue al TextBox con la tecla Tab, pero si llego haciendo clic con el ratón, no lo selecciona (supongo que el propio clic del ratón deselecciona posteriormente el texto).

¿Cómo puedo desactivar ese comportamiento? Es decir, quiero que al hacer clic con el ratón el texto se quede seleccionado exactamente igual que cuando lo hago con el teclado.

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Llamando a este método extensor en el Contructor o Load de tu Window lo lograrás:

```
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApplication5
{
    public static class Extensions
    {

        public static void SelectedAllForever(this TextBox source)
        {
            source.GotFocus   += (sender, e) => source.SelectAll(); ;
            source.IsMouseDirectlyOverChanged += (sender, e) => source.SelectAll();
        }

    }
}
```

en tu Constructor o Load:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.textBox.SelectedAllForever();
    }
```

Comment: Ese no es exactamente el comportamiento que quiero, ya que cuando hago clic no selecciona el texto, sino que lo hace cuando saco el puntero del TextBox. Lo que busco es que en el momento de hacer clic se quede el texto seleccionado directamente. En Angular se hace con ng-mouseup="$event.preventDefault();", pero en C# no lo consigo

Comment: Lo acabo de modificar, creo que esto si que es lo que buscas.

Comment: Al final lo he conseguido con el evento PreviewMouseUp